# Can not connect Jenkins agent to controller

Tags: windows, jenkins, jenkins-agent

I set up Jenkins on a Windows 7 64 bit PC, and installed a Jenkins agent service on another Win7 64 PC.
The controller PC gives this error:

```
Connection was broken
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.peek(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peek(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$ReaderThread.run(Channel.java:1127)
```

What can I do to diagnose the problem?

**[Update]**
The error is shown when I go to the Nodes page. The added agent is displayed as being disconnected. And when I click on the node Name, the above error is displayed.

**[Update 2]**
When a job was forced to run on the agent, it just worked. And afterwards, the agent was displayed as being connected in the node page.
Now I come to think of it, I did not try to queue multiple jobs. Perhaps that would have triggered the execution to the agent as well?

Anyway, I've got my *CI farm* up & running now :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to start the slave via browser, log as administrator to the slave machine and go to the node page on jenkins, if you are logged as jenkins admin you'll see a slave start icon, this will download and execute the slave process.

[start slave screenshot](http://jacovanstaden.files.wordpress.com/2011/03/jenkinsslavelaunchpage.jpg?w=600&h=243)

Once you get this working you can update it as a windows service via the slave java application menu “File->Install as Windows Service”.

Comment: Yes, that's what I already did. I managed to install a slave jenkins installation as a windows service, and on the slave side, it looks ok. It is the master that tells me a connection with the slave could not be established.

Comment: @parvus so the web pages shows the node as offline? Or that error appears only when you start a job?

Comment: When a job is started, it is always executed on the master jenkins installation.

Comment: @parvus You can force execution on a specific slave in the job configuration.

Comment: Great! When I did that, it worked! (Well, the run failed, but that was due to a missing environment variable). And afterwards, when I checked the node page again, it was marked as connected! Hurray!

Answer (score 2):

If you're running jenkins through a HTTPS connection using a self signed certificate open `jenkins-slave.xml` and add `-noCertificateCheck` to the arguments list.

Answer (score 1):

Look in your $JENKINS_HOME folder for the slave logs, they might contain more information.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of those files. Unfortunately, they do not contain more information. :-(