# master slave in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, master-slave

I have jenkins 1.595 installed in my system which will work as the master for my master slave setup.I have followed each and every step given in master slave setup jenkins(https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines).I am able to get the launch button on my slave but when I am trying to run agent It shows me CouldNotLoadArgumentException .I have also tried running the agent through commandline but it still shows me the same error.

`CouldNotLoadArgumentException[ Could not load file/URL specified: http://localhost:8080/computer/Slave%20machine%20P/slave-agent.jnlp]
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`

Please suggest the reason why I am getting this error

Comment: This is not a NullPointerException. Can you please clarify ?

Comment: Sorry,It is CouldNotLoadArgument Exception.I have edited it.Thanks for correcting me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jnlp url you have configured uses "localhost" as the hostname for the server.
This can't work, you need to configure the server url with it's actual hostname so that it can be resolved from the slave(s).

Comment: thanks mate it worked but I am still not able to run the agent on slave it is giving me java.lang.exception.the server rejected the connection exception

Comment: Could you maybe attach a log from the Jenkins client or the server ?

Comment: Also, please read thru http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634760/can-not-connect-slave-to-master for possibly more info.